# How to remove multiple array from a oject with index of item from array in Jacascript/Jquery Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have array**Items**  on following format:

​Remove  elements from in Javascript/jQuery

```
{images: Array(4) [ "abcd.png", "bcd.jpg", "def.jpg", … ]
​
itemIds: Array(4) [ "1", "3", "2", … ]}

var revid=$(this).attr('data');
```

Above images and itemIds are stored on `storedNames` by parsing JSONfrom localstorage.

**revid** returns any values which is on **itemIds**

This is giving me not a function error:

```
var indexed = storedNames.findIndex(item => item.itemIds === 'revid');
```

1 ) How can I find the indexof **itemIds**  in **storedNames** ? (solved)

​2) How can I remove all item from object(both array) having index **value = indexed** For example :
I want to remove : abcd.png and 1

?

Comment: `storedNames` is an _object_, that doesn't have a `findeIndex` method. What you want to search in, is `storedNames.itemIds`

Comment: And none of your itemIds has the actual string value `revid` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @CBroe

I solved this way:

```
 var indexed = storedNames.itemIds.findIndex(item => item === revid);







 var newObj = {};
 Object.keys(storedNames).forEach(key =>{
  newObj[key]=storedNames[key].filter((item,i) => i !=indexToRemove);
     });
    
  localStorage.setItem("localstorageItems", JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Here **localstorageItems** is the localstorage object having multiple arrays.